# jQuery AJAX response coming as string blob

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blob

I am calling AWS S3 to retrieve images using AJAX call in jQuery 3.3.0 and instead of getting a *blob* object, I am receiving the response as `"[object Blob]"`. Please let me know if I have to provide further details.

Please find the code below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "my_path/download_image.php",
    data: {
        name: "my_name"
    },
    cache: false,
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var image = new Image();
        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        self.DownloadStudentImages(students, index + 1);
        image.src = url.createObjectURL(data);
        self.SavePic(imageFilename);
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

Comment: At least, you need to provide the related code :)

Comment: Added the code herewith

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issue. Usually, AWS response from PHP is in string format unless it is encoded explicitly. So, I am sending base64 from PHP and in the javascript side, I am converting it to a byte array and thus into a blob which fixes the issue.